# Handling serde error and other error type?

Tags: rust

I have the following function of `export_directory`.

```rust
// For handling multiple error type
type BoxResult<T> = Result<T, Box<std::error::Error>>;

fn export_directory(dir: &Directory, export_path: &str) -> BoxResult<String> {
  let mut file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).truncate(true).create(true).open(export_path)?;
  serde_json::to_string(dir).or_else(|err| Err(Box::new(err)))
}

fn main() {
  let mut dir = Directory::new();
  export_directory(&dir, "export_path.json");
}
```

When I compile the code, it gives me

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:98:3
   |
96 | fn export_directory(dir: &Directory, export_path: &str) -> BoxResult<String> {
   |                                                            ----------------- expected `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>` because of return type
97 |   let mut file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).truncate(true).create(true).open(export_path)?;
98 |   serde_json::to_string(dir).or_else(|err| Err(Box::new(err)))
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait std::error::Error, found struct `serde_json::error::Error`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, std::boxed::Box<serde_json::error::Error>>`
```

But when referring to [serde documentation](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/error/struct.Error.html), the `serde_json::error::Error` has already implemented `Error` trait. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rustc failed to automatically infer that the `Box` inside the closure wants to be `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` or `Box<serde_json::Error>`. You have to tell the compiler that you're actually creating a boxed trait object rather than a boxed struct.

On the other hand, you can't directly call `Box::<std::error::Error>::new` because `Error` does not extend `std::marker::Sized`.

However, a `serde_json::Error` can indeed be boxed into a boxed `std::error::Error`. So you can force this conversion using the `as` operator:

```
result.map_err(|err| Box::new(err) as Box<dyn std::error::Error>)
```

[Working example on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e18d3d2d55d4e66f2d1a4e3a50e122a)

Comment: It seems `cargo clippy` doesn't like this code; `map_err(|err| Box::new(err) as Box<dyn std::error::Error>)` should be used instead.

Comment: @ynn thanks, no idea why I chose to use the less intuitive `or_else` when I wrote this answer.

Comment: Ah, I just copied it from the question.